# Can not update 'App\User' with mysql command

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to update `App/User` value in `core_model_has_roles` table using a mysql command.

`core_model_has_roles` table has `role_id`, `model_type`, and `model_id` fields.

I want to update `model_type` column with this command: `UPDATE core_model_has_roles SET model_type = 'App\User' WHERE model_id = 3022` but it is showing `AppUser` in `model_type` column. So how can I update `App\User` value? Could anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE core_model_has_roles SET model_type = 'App\\User' WHERE model_id = 3022` - You probably just need to use `App\\Model` instead of `App\Model`, since ``\`` is an escape character. Or, `App\User::class`; should return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with MySQL. the backslash is an escape character. In order to use it either you need to use quote or another backslash ThereYou can use the following code to update

```
 UPDATE 
 core_model_has_roles 
 SET model_type = 'App\User' 
 WHERE model_id = 3022
```

Or

```
 UPDATE 
 core_model_has_roles 
 SET model_type = QUOTE('App\User')
 WHERE model_id = 3022
```